# & selector in less not working when merging is on in Magento 2

Tags: css, magento, less, magento2

Anybody know why this selector sometimes do not work when in Product Mode and CSS merging is enabled on Magento 2

Ex.

```
a {
   padding: 0;
   line-height: 19px;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   padding-left: 27px;
   background-position: left center;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;

   &:hover {
       text-decoration: none;
       color: @color-orange;
   }

   &.offer {
       background-image: url('../images/ic_offer_gray.png');
   }
}
```

The "&.offer" part works in developer mode & merging is OFF but when in production mode and merging is ON the style is not getting included in the compiled css.

I'm currently using Magento 2.2.6 but i believe i have the same issue in the previous versions.

The weird thing is it works on some part of my less code where i use parent selector "&" that's why i can't really point out the issue.